# Passing values from database to the UI using Automation Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mariadb

I am trying to pass values from my MySQL database to the UI using Automation Selenium WebDriver with Java? The code is returning only the first row.

Here are the database values:

[image]

I have changed the code many times using for int loop and have received different kind of errors such as:

- before start of result set
- after end of result set

I am unable to figure it out.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Basically, In this case I have firstName and lastName which are passed via the database to the UI. I want to pass those values to my test case. I do not want to hard code. Currently, I have a table with 2 columns and one column is firstName and second column is lastName.

I want to Iterate through the database and pick these values wherever I want. SendKeys.

Here is my test case code file.

FacebookTest file code below.

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertThrows;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import selenium.ReadExcel;


public class FacebookTest 
{
    @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "unchecked" }) 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    //public static void facebookTest()
    {       
        // pointing to the file, now FF must have pointer as well in Selenium 3.0
        // WebDriver

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver.exe");
        // OPEN FF
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        DBTestData db = new DBTestData();


        // ENTER URL
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/");             

        try
        {   
            ResultSet testData = db.data("","");

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            {               
                String firstName = testData.getString("firstName");
                String lastName = testData.getString("lastName");           

                System.out.println(firstName);
                System.out.println(lastName);
                driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_e")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_e")).sendKeys(firstName);
                driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_g")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_g")).sendKeys(lastName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {           
            driver.quit();          
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my DB file where I am getting the values from database and returning it to the test case 101 - see code below.

DBTestData code file below.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBTestData {
    // public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unused" })
    // public static String data() throws Exception

    public static ResultSet data(String firstName, String lastName) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
    {       
            // Accessing driver from the JAR file
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            // Creating a variable for the connection called "con"
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "username", "password");
            // after localhost:3306 is where you will put the name of the database
            // jdbc:mysql://localhost:3606/testdb ---> this is a database
            // root is a database user and password too

            // our query below
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM test_data");

            // creating variable to execute query
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            // List sqlData = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList<String> sqlData = new ArrayList<String>();

                while (result.next()) 
                {               
                    sqlData.add(firstName = result.getString(firstName));
                    sqlData.add(lastName = result.getString(lastName));

                }
                    return result;              
    }
}
```

Let me know how I can achieve this concept. Once I get the basics I will utilize the same file other test cases.   Why can't we use the same concept 2D array to pass the values from database to UI?

Comment: What line are you getting that error on?

Comment: I have provided screenshot of my database. I am not getting error. I am only getting the first row returned only. I want all rows to be entered in the UI. It is only entering the data from the first row. And then execution stops. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think  you forgot to iterate through `testdata` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Where did I forget to Iterate ? In the FacebookTest file or DBTestData file? In which line of code I need to put in for loop?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I resolved my issue.   I used  a do while loop in my test case and It was able to fetch all the data from all rows and Iterate it in my webpage.

Here is the code below.

FacebookTest code file:

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertThrows;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import selenium.ReadExcel;


public class FacebookTest 
{
 @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "unchecked" }) 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
 { 
 // pointing to the file, now FF must have pointer as well in Selenium 3.0 WebDriver
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver.exe");

 // OPEN FF
 FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

 DBTestData db = new DBTestData(); 

 // ENTER URL
 driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/");

 try
 {

 ResultSet testData = db.data("","");

 do 
 {
   String firstName = testData.getString(1);
   String lastName = testData.getString(2);

   driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_e")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_e")).sendKeys(firstName);
   driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_g")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_g")).sendKeys(lastName); 

 }
 while(testData.next()); 



 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally 
 { 
 driver.quit(); 
 }
 }
}
```

Here is my DBTestData file:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DBTestData 
{
 public static ResultSet data(String firstName, String lastName) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
 { 

 // Accessing driver from the JAR file
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

 // Creating a variable for the connection called "con"
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "username", "password");

 // after localhost:3306 is where you will put the name of the database
 // jdbc:mysql://localhost:3606/testdb ---> this is a database
 // root is a database user and password too

 // our query below
 PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM test_data");

 // creating variable to execute query
 ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(); 

 // store all the rows data into one variable
 ArrayList<String> sqlData = new ArrayList<String>(); 

 while(result.next())
 {
   sqlData.add(firstName= result.getString("firstName"));
   sqlData.add(lastName = result.getString("lastName")); 
   break;
 } 
 return result;
 } 
}
```

So, how do I properly close the database connection?

And how do I Iterate until n number of rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

con.close(); is command for closing db